# python3 module v:"module.classObj"

Tags: python-3.x

I use python3.7 and i had see someone use code like this

```py
import mitmproxy.log
import mitmproxy.master
import mitmproxy.options

log: "mitmproxy.log.Log"
master: "mitmproxy.master.Master"
options: "mitmproxy.options.Options"
```

is mean that `log` is an instance of `mitmproxy.log.Log`?
But i try terminal, error occured

```
In [8]: import http

In [9]: s:'http.server'

In [10]: s
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-ded5ba42480f> in <module>
----> 1 s

NameError: name 's' is not defined
```

Comment: `s:'http.server'` just defines a *type*, there's still no value.

Comment: @jonrsharpe   python3 type is like  `v=12 #typing int`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say, but `s: 'http.server'` is definitely a [type annotation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/).

Comment: @jonrsharpe you are right, i wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing here is called annotations. So in your case `log` is not a instance of `mitmproxy.log.Log`. See by yourself:

```
>>> log.__annotations__
'mitmproxy.log.Log'
```

If you want to create an instance of the class `Class` please use this syntax:

```
s = Class()
```